# Spring MVC Post not working, Client is hanging

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Got a problem with post method in Spring. When i'm trying to post object to database, the client app is hanging and i need to terminate it. Posting the object with curl is working normally. I'm getting log:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->dareq.Point["points"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->dareq.Point["points"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->dareq.Point["points"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->dareq.Point["points"]
```

Client side:

Point class:

```
public class Point {
private Long id;
private List<String> bssid = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Double> rssi = new ArrayList<>();
private double x;
private double y;

public Point()
{

}

public Point(Long id, List<String> bssid, List<Double> rssi, double x, double y){
    this.id = id;
    this.bssid = bssid;
    this.rssi = rssi;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Post function:

```
public void postPoint()
{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:5000/points", this, this.getClass());
}
```

Server side:

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/points")
Points newPoints(@RequestBody Points newPoints){
    return repository.save(newPoints);
}
```

Points class:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Points {

private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
@Column
@ElementCollection
private List<String> bssid;
@Column
@ElementCollection
private List<Double> rssi;
private double x;
private double y;

Points (){
};

Points(List<String> bssid, List<Double> rssi, double x, double y){
    this.bssid=bssid;
    this.rssi=rssi;
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}
}
```

Checking logs on AWS server, when i try to post object on client, a lot of get methods are called:

```
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:31 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:32 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:32 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:32 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:32 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:32 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:33 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:33 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:33 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:33 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:33 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:33 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:33 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:34 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:34 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:34 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:34 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:34 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:34 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:34 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:35 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:35 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:35 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:35 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:35 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
78.28.26.200 - - [07/Jan/2019:00:34:36 +0000] "GET /points/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Java/1.8.0_172" "-"
```

I will really appreciate any help. Thanks